# trying to read json data from file, How to make single json property as case insensitive at "auto btest = array[i].at(L"Test").as_bool();" in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

auto bTest = array[i].at(L"Test").as_bool();

Here Test should be case insensitive while reading from json.

so if json has test, it should allow

if json has teST, it should allow.

I am trying read and write the JSON, renaming one property to camelCase. The new updated Json property throws error for old Json data. since, that json is not updated with new modified property.

How read make the Old property in Read() to allow accept new change and How to make the new property to allow old Json property data.

for example,
Old json:
"pets": [{
"Dog":true
}]

In Read()
auto bDog = array[i].at(L"Dog").as_bool();

In Write()
auto bDog = array[i].at(L"dog").as_bool();
New Json:
"pets": [{
"dog":true
}]

Now How do I read old Json with modified property.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: casablanca c++ json

Answer (score 0):

JSON is case sensitive.
One option is to first scan the file and replace the tags with the lower case equivalent.

The other option is to fork one of the json parsers and change it to always change case to lower, while it reads.

I'd say that the test for reading case insensitive is itself the wrong thing to do, unless the file generation is out of your control. Ideally, you'd have a test for the generator of the json that validates that the schema is followed right, including the case.

Comment: Actually, the old json data contains properties in no case, updating the new json data to camel-case. while reading the old json data with new camel cased properties throwing error. lowercase is not so effective.

Comment: Then, given that you can easily create a replacement list, you should just do a find and replace on the old file and make it camel case regardless of what it was. Then, you wont have to worry about case while parsing the json.

Comment: Many ways to do that find-replace. Here are some: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271078/replace-strings-in-a-file-based-on-a-list-of-strings-and-a-list-of-corresponding

Comment: json libraries don't do that to the best of my knowledge. Here's another option. Once you parse the file, iterate over it as an array of arrays and while you do, build another json object, but with the keys converted to what they need to be. Then use this json object and only do camel case lookups.  To convert the keys in the previous step I mentioned, you can do a tolower() and then lookup the camelCase name for that from a list.  Let me know if you need help with this and I'll try to find some time this week to write sample code.